# how java application can communicate with android application?

Tags: java, android

how java application can communicate with android application(ex.sending file between two app) by WiFi 
i try to develop a java application that can send types of files to android application

Answer (score 2):

Just use standard Java networking APIs if they're operating over WiFi.

Comment: but i want to send this files between the two apps through p2p connection is this available?

Comment: I don't see why not. Plenty of standard API code for doing this thing as well as Java libraries that build on that.

Comment: OK so how can i start pl z